# how to convert negative number to binary in java?

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to convert a negative long number (e.g. -1065576264718330231L) to binary.
First, I convert negative number to positive one by removing the sign;
Second, I get the binary of the result from first step;

then I get stuck with "add one" to the binary result of the second step,that is :

[image]

please! how to implement the third step?
or do you have other better solutions?!

http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/05/binary-rep-of-negative-numbers-in-java.html

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. But if you have a long, then it is already converted into binary. If you want to access this binary representation of the long as a string then you can use the `toBinaryString` method of the Long class eg: `Long.toBinaryString(-1477552144L)`

Comment: oh my god. I even don't know it has this method. that's what I want actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the long value is `-1065576264718330231L`.

```java
      long v = -1065576264718330231L;

      System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(v));
```

Or you can code the algorithm yourself

```java
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while (v != 0) {
         sb.append(v < 0 ? '1'
               : '0');
         v <<= 1;
      }
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

If  you want to convert a positive number to negative using `2's complement` you can do the following:

```java
      long pos = 23;
      long neg = ~pos + 1;
      System.out.println(pos);
      System.out.println(neg);
```

But all Strings, ints, longs, etc. are inherently stored in binary and are displayed in different formats based on context.

Answer (score 3):

Signed integers/longs use the *two-complements* notation:

Say you have -6:

```
6 = 000..000 110 binary
    111..111 001 one's complement
    111..111 010 add 1
-6 = 111..111 010
```

The advantage is that normal binary addition works (-6+6=0), there is just one 0.

Of you could simply subtract 6 from 0:

```
      000
      110
   ------ -
        0
       1   borrow 1 (all ones at the top)
      0
...111

111...111010 = -6

Note:
If one borrows (subtracts one of) 0000000, one actually uses an overflow:
                               (1)0000000 which minus 1 delivers
                                  1111111
```

Goodies:

```
long n = -1065576264718330231L;
System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(n, 2));
System.out.println(Long.toString(n, 2));
```